# Dealing with overlapping control/patient groups in SPM

Tags: matlab, neuroimaging

Seeing as this question combines statistics, neuroimaging and programming I wasn't sure where to ask it, I apologize if it needs to be moved.

I have data from a study where subjects were asked to name unique items (famous people, etc) and non-unique ones (animals, etc). Using a validated cut off, subjects are designated as anomic for unique items (1 = yes, 0 = no) and for non-unique ones. I have run analyses in SPM to find the regions of grey matter loss in those anomic for unique items vs controls (a large set of cognitively normal adults, matched for age and sex) as well as nonunique vs controls. I now want to determine the areas unique (if any) to each condition as well as the common region(s) of atrophy.

I thought about doing a conjunction analysis in SPM. The table is organized as follows:

[image]

I have two issues:

- many subjects are anomic for both unique and nonunique items. Given this overlap, will a conjunction analysis in SPM be statistically valid?
- if so, when the model is being fitted in SPM the subjects that are not anomic for a particular category (the covar_unique = 0 and covar_nonunique=0) will be included as 'controls', but they are not controls, and I don't know how to avoid this

I appreciate any input anyone may have!

Hugo

Comment: Actually I think running a full factorial as opposed to a regression will work.

Answer (score 1):

First issue: I'm not really an expert on this, but I'll attempt an answer based on what I found at [mindhive](http://mindhive.mit.edu/node/60). The main point of contention regarding conjunction analyses seems to be how to adjust the $p$-values used for the single contrasts. The standard way to adjust ($\sqrt[n]{p}$ for $n$ contrasts) assumes independence. Since independence in your case is a problem, a simple workaround would be *not* to adjust $p$-values, but just to compute the single contrasts in the normal, properly FWE-corrected way, and then define the conjunction area as the set of voxels where both contrasts give a corrected-significant result. As long as this doesn't kill your effect, this should be the way to go, because it is the most conservative approach you can use.

Second issue: You have to encode your controls explicitly, using another regressor `control`, and then define your two contrasts as `[1, 0, -1]` and `[0, 1, -1]` with respect to the three regressors `[covar_unique, covar_nonunique, control]`.

Hope this helps. Btw. I think it would be great if we could get an SPM- or neuroimaging statistics-community on stackexchange; the SPM mailing list is just a big mess imho.